# What is the Domain of this Mellin Transform?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, mellin-transform

I am trying to evaluate an integral of the form
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\gamma(\tau)=\int_0^\infty\text{d}u\,e^{-\tau u}\Big(1+\frac1u\Big)\frac1{\log(u)^2+\pi^2}
\end{equation}
and decided to expand the exponential, so that I can write the solution as a power series
$$\gamma(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,c_n\tau^n\ ,$$
where
$$c_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\big(\varphi(n+1)+\varphi(n)\big)$$
and
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\varphi(s)=\int_0^\infty\text{d}u\,u^{s-1}\frac1{\log(u)^2+\pi^2}\equiv\big\{\mathcal{M}f\big\}(s)
\end{equation}
is the Mellin transform this question is about.

Though I have no proof for this, the first integral for $\gamma(\tau)$ seems to converge for all $\tau>0$. By rewriting it as a power series I exchanged summation and integration which is only a valid operation if the Mellin transform $\varphi$ exists for all $s\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

I think it does not exist for any $s$ with $\text{Re}(s)>0$ as the integrand in its definition diverges for large $u$ but WolframAlpha happily gives me the Mellin transform as
$$\big\{\mathcal{M}f\big\}(s)=e^{-i\pi s}\ ,$$
implying that all $c_n$ vanish which, as numerical integration suggests, can not be the case.

My questions now is, what is the domain of the Mellin transform of $f$? Does the vanishing of the coefficients $c_n$ come down to the fact that I should not have exchanged summation and integration?
Also any help in evaluating $\gamma(\tau)$ is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mathematica indicates $\mathcal{M}_u\left[\frac{1}{\log^2(u)+\pi^2}\right](n)=e^{-\pi \sqrt{-n^2}}$ is only valid for $\Re(n)=0$. Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica don't always generate the conditions for the results of integrals and transforms, but you can force Mathematica to generate the conditions by specifying GenerateConditions->True.